# How to create array or Collection of anonymous class objects

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

I need to create an array or collection of anonymous class objects.

For example the toString of my constructor is:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%10s%12s%12d", getFirstName(), getLastName(), getAge());
}
```

I can create a list of `MyClass` objects:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

But now I need to override the `toString` method with an anonymous class
and make a new Collection with a new `toString` method:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s%12s%12d", getFirstName(), getLastName(), getAge());
    }
};
```

How can this be implemented ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just use a `List<User>`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use anonymous classes for this? You'll be creating a new class (not just object) for every element, and this is quite a clumsy approach. What are you trying to do? Have your `User` be displayed in different ways at different times?

Comment: I agree with @Kayaman. You issue sounds IMHO like an OO design issue - ie. you should probably use multiple deriving classes which will implement toString differently, but will still be based on the same base class.

Comment: he's not creating a new anon class for each element. He's creating an instance of an anon subclass of `MyClass`. To answer the question: Use `List<? extends MyClass>` for example.

Comment: for example i need to change toString method

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer but he can't create a new instance of the same anonymous class, so every object with the changed `toString()` will be a new anonymous subclass. 1 element 1 extra class, 5 elements 5 extra classes.

Comment: @PouriaMohseni but why do you need to change it? You can't just "change" methods in Java, the language doesn't allow it. What is the root reason that makes you want to change `toString()`?

Comment: what do you think `new MyClass() {....}` does? It creates exactly one new class, not 5

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer and once you have a list of 5 elements (unless you put the same element 5 times in the list, which seems unlikely) you have 5 new classes. You do realize it creates an anonymous subclass of `MyClass`, right? So if he wants users with different properties, he'll have different anonymous subclasses.

Comment: no, you don't. You still have only one anon class, but you have 5 instances of it.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer that's just not true. Calling `u1.getClass().equals(u2.getClass());` would return false, as they're not the same class. Now why don't you go test it out, apologize and then remove your comments so we can help a person who's even more lost than you (and whose question it is, before you came in with your misunderstandings).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the code. Show me the code above that creates 5 different classes? And the question was already answered. If you have instances of an anon subclass, you can stick it in a `List<? extends MyClass>` if you like.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer You said "You still have only one anon class, but you have 5 instances of it", which can't happen unless you use reflection to create the new instances of the same class. You also don't need a generic wildcard `<? extends MyClass>`, a simple `<MyClass>` is enough. The issue is with creating an object with a "changed" method, and his proposed solution would just create new classes (I assume you don't object to that anymore) unnecessarily, and the solution would be bad even if we didn't care about extra classes being created.

Comment: ?!? Where did he mention creating new classes? His example code is creating one new anon subclass. Not 5 or 7. You seem to assume he wants a new subclass per object.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer if he ever wants more than one user (and he has a `List` which is known for accepting more than one object, not to mention he's explicitly saying he wants a collection with objects having different `toString()` methods), he'll have to do the same to them. So for every user with a modified `toString()` he'll have a new distinct anonymous subclass. Come on, it's not that difficult to understand. We've hijacked the question from it's original purpose. We can move this to chat if you really want me to explain this to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167702/discussion-between-kayaman-and-jochen-bedersdorfer).

Comment: Dude, I've been doing Java since 1.0. No need to explain this. But nowhere in this question does he say needs a different `toString` implementation of each user object. He just needs a subclass for his user objects. 
Read the question again.

Comment: Anything else doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer whether the `toString()` implementation is different or not doesn't matter. I really suggest you come to the chat. Unless you're afraid that you're wrong? I started Java back when 1.2 just came out, surely you'll know how to put me in my place?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer the explanation's in the chat. Let me know if you didn't understand something.

Comment: `and he has a List which is known for accepting more than one object,` you are so cute. I guess this is just a case of neither the original author nor us understanding exactly what is being asked here. 
And if you say, the code below creates 5 classes, you need to show me $2 to $5.
`
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { objs.add(new Object() {public String toString() { return "bubu"; }
        });
`

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer seriously. Take your code snippet and see the `getClass()` of each of the elements. Then tell me it's not creating 5 different classes. I mean seriously. That's like saying `new Integer(1); new Integer(1);` creates one object instead of two. I'm going to stop here though. If you claim that it **doesn't** create new classes (even though you can easily verify that), then fine. There are people who insist on even crazier things. Maybe you're just trolling because you're ashamed that you were wrong, it doesn't matter. I'm moving on to newer questions.

Answer (score 0):

As said you can't change a method in a Java class, so you have several options depending on what you need to do.

You can create a `UserWrapper` which wraps a `User`, overrides `toString()` and all other method calls are delegated to the `User` object it wraps.

You can modify your `User` class to include the format String, which would allow you to do something like `user.setFormat("%s%12s%12d");` and the `toString()` would use that for display.

You could take the formatting out of `User` completely, since it's not really its job anyway from a design point of view, and when you need to display a user's details, it would be done in a different class like `String str = String.format("%s%12s%12d", user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getAge());`.

The last one is probably the most sound design-wise, you would do that where you intend to display the contents of the list (and not rely on the default `toString()` implementation of the list either), something like

```
public void printList() { // Or build the String and return if you don't
    for(User u : myList)  // want to display it here
        System.out.println(format(u));
}
private String format(User u) {
    return String.format(""%s%12s%12d", u.getFirstName(), u.getLastName(), u.getAge());
}
```